# Why does R.all with R.both does not equal R.allPass with the same arguments?

Tags: ramda.js

I'm just learning while doing ramda.js. Well, there are many ways to reach a goal with ramda, but there is on thing I do not understand.

I would like to check the input for an array of strings that all match one regular expression. I thought I could do it `R.all(R.both(isString, isRegExp))`, but it seems to deliver a `true` when the input is a number.
As expected `R.allPass([isString, isRegExp])` gives a `false` with a number input.

But can anyone please explain me why R.all is returning a true? Or what and where is mistake (in thinking)?

Complete code:

```
var isString = R.is(String),
  isMyRegExp = R.test(/^[a-z]+$/),
  isMyRegExpString = R.both(isString, isMyRegExp),
  isArrayOfMyRegExpStrings = R.all(isMyRegExpString),
  isArrayOfMyRegExpStringsPass = R.allPass([isString, isMyRegExp]),
  result = {
    'all': isArrayOfMyRegExpStrings(9),
    'allPass': isArrayOfMyRegExpStringsPass(9)
};
console.log(result);

// {
//   all: true,
//   allPass: false
// }
```

https://codepen.io/Eisenhardt/pen/PKLZqj

PS:
I know that I could shorten conditions with just the regexp, but there could be other situations where I need both conditions to be true. eg. isArrayOfNumber and sumOfNumbersOver50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `R.all` is expecting a list of values to test. Due to the way the function is implemented it is treating the `9` in your example as an empty list, resulting in a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) and evaluating to `true`.

Comment: I see, so the difference between `R.all` and `R.allPass` is that `R.all` really expects an array (like object) as argument in the resulting function and `R.allPass` don't.

okay, thank you!

Comment: Correct, `R.all` expects a single predicate function and a list of values to test, while `R.allPass` a list of predicate functions and a single value to test.